# ul selector works but not the class that's applied to the ul

Tags: html, css

I'm curious as to why my code works when I use "list-style: none" on the ul selector but not when I use it on the class selector which is applied to the ul.

I've tried applying "list-style: none" to .navigation, which is the ul class, but it doesn't work. The bullet points are still there.

```
<nav>

  <ul class=“navigation”>
    <li><a href=“#”>About</a></li>
    <li><a href=“#”>Pricing</a></li>
    <li><a href=“#”>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class=“button”>
    <a class=“btn-main” href=“#”>Sign up</a>
    <a class=“btn-hot” href=“#”>Get a quote</a>
  </div>  

</nav>
```

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

$color-primary: #f9ed69; //yellow color

nav {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: $color-primary;
}

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
}
```

I would expect the .navigation selector to work the same as the ul selector.

Comment: If you wrote it exactly as above, you need to change all typographical quotes to regular quotes.

Comment: Fix your curly quotes, `“button”`. It should be either `'button'` or `"button"`

Comment: you are using wrong quotes -
 
    class=“navigation”
correct one - 
    class="navigation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are the wrong type

```css
.navigation {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class=“navigation”>
  <!--wrong quotes-->
  <li><a href=“#”>About</a></li>
  <li><a href=“#”>Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href=“#”>Contact</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="navigation">
  <li><a href=“#”>About</a></li>
  <li><a href=“#”>Pricing</a></li>
  <li><a href=“#”>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation marks around the classes names are messing things up.
Try rewriting them with something like this " or ' not “

Answer (score 0):

you are using wrong quotes - 
   class=“navigation” 
correct one - 
   **class="navigation"**

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of issues happens a lot when you have a library with a `navigation` class as part of its pre-defined classes.

Before you continue, change your quotes to "" and try again. If that didn't work make sure that your stylesheet is imported after the libraries. e.g if you have bootstrap, import bootstrap first and then your stylesheet file at the bottom.

Can you try using:

```
nav > .navigation{
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Sometimes it's not always a must to use classes to style your elements, but this depends on what you personally to do ofcourse. Style attributes are global and often will clash with your CSS UI Libraries you might be using.  So in your case I would personally use:

```
nav > ul{
list-style: none;
}
```